# LinkedIN Oauth issue while getting accessToken

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I was trying to integrate linkedIn oauth into my website, But I'm stuck on this error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

I'm getting this error when i was trying to get the accessToken using authorization code.

Request & response view from livehttpheaders are as follows

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken

POST /uas/oauth2/accessToken HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://www.clovedigital.com/oauth/oauth_lnk.pl?code=AQRLhiv3oDKfFdN2ccXtSCOaC3ujQncdJ1QeFYw_c6iQVvrvy_M4w13IYny3cIzpPWzBPmOaI8DMZFp8pjbBvJHeni4MhbF5ig27SLkmVUHHKQYwB2U&state=mbclqkji
Content-Length: 277
Origin: https://www.clovedigital.com
Connection: keep-alive
grant_type=authorization_code&code=AQRLhiv3oDKfFdN2ccXtSCOaC3ujQncdJ1QeFYw_c6iQVvrvy_M4w13IYny3cIzpPWzBPmOaI8DMZFp8pjbBvJHeni4MhbF5ig27SLkmVUHHKQYwB2U&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.clovedigital.com%2Foauth%2Foauth_lnk.pl&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 220
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Even though the response code is 200, I haven't receive any accessToken as response. Instead I could see those Cross origin error message in console. Need help in resolving this issue

Comment: Did you manage to solve this in the meantime? I'm having the same issue.. I guess it has to be something really stupid, just can't figure it out..

Comment: @kecer After getting the code, make the link [link](https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=AQRLhiv3oDKfFdN2ccXtSCOaC3ujQncdJ1QeFYw_c6iQVvrvy_M4w13IYny3cIzpPWzBPmOaI8DMZFp8pjbBvJHeni4MhbF5ig27SLkmVUHHKQYwB2U&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.clovedigital.com%2Foauth%2Foauth_lnk.pl&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx) and post it in browser address bar and click go. It is working..

Comment: @kecer Then I used php curl to get the accessToken and then user's email address. If you need detailed answer about how I did, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: yeah, I know the link is working, it's just rejecting CORS. using php to do this seems hacky to me and not applicable in my case. hopefully somebody will come here and give some different solution

Comment: Hope so.. Some said doing it in javascript will work. But It also didn't work for me. If you get it working, don't forget to post an answer below